# HighChart zoom in x-axis last label align wrongly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a `datetime` chart with `zoomType : x` and set the `showLastLabel` to `false`, but the last label still showing and with wrong position when I zoom

Before zoom:
[image: Screen Capture before zoom]

After zoom:
[image: Screen Capture after zoom]
 
This screen capture shows the last label (30 Jul) appear beside the label (27 Jul) 
How can I solve this problem? Thanks all!

Below is my code for the x-Axis:

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            //rotation: -90,   //For vertical display for the x-axis labels                                          
            y: 20,
            formatter: function () {
                var ex = this.axis.getExtremes();
                var day = Highcharts.dateFormat('%e', this.value);
                var mth = Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value);
                if (((ex.max - ex.min) / (24 * 3600 * 1000)) > 300)
                    return mth;
                else
                    return day + '<br>' + mth;
            },
            overflow: 'justify',
            align: 'center',
            //StaggerLines: 2, // not working
            //step: 2,
            //y: 30,      
            useHTML: true                                 
        },
        minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
        minRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 12,
        tickPixelInterval: $('#' + container).width() / 12, // not working after zoom
        title: {
            text: x_title,
            offset: 50
        },
        showLastLabel: false, //Hide the last label 1/1 to show again
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: true,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,

    },
```

Comment: I think I found the solution, after I comment the usehtml, everything is OK, but I still don't know why

Comment: Could you upload and link your "after zoom" image? The link is to "delete".

Comment: link updated, thanks!

Comment: Could you reproduce issue in jsFiddle? I will check this.

Comment: I had made a simplified one [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kaii007/Pn8E3/), but no problem found, is this highChart version problem? I am using v2.3 in my project.

Comment: You can add spacingRight and disable crop (by setting it as false), and overflow as justify.